# can we connect more than two devices with bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple bluetooth connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943182/multiple-bluetooth-connection)

can we connect more than two devices with blue-tooth to play a game. I am totally new to Android. I was thinking to write application for card game that play 4 players. I heard that blue-tooth communicate only between 2 mobiles. I want to dig the background before I continue. That's why I ask this.

I appreciate your ideas about this and any hints to develop this application also are appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943182/multiple-bluetooth-connection.  As an alternative, consider using WiFi Direct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251610/wifi-direct-android-4-0-with-multiple-3-devices

Comment: oops I miss thess, bad searching. thanks. I will check