# WiFi Direct (Android 4.0) with multiple (3+) devices Bidirectional

Tags: android, network-programming, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I want to do the same thing as this post : [WiFi Direct (Android 4.0) with multiple (3+) devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251610/wifi-direct-android-4-0-with-multiple-3-devices)

but with bidirectionnal messages.

A -> B and B -> A

B -> C and C -> B

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have to create a wifi direct group, and all of your devices have to connect to the group owner device. After this, all devices in this group knows the group owner IP address. Now you have to do these steps:

- All device (except the group owner) have to send a message (the content of the message is unrelevant) to the group owner. You can do this with the group owner address.
- Now the group owner receive the message. This is not important, but the socket is! You can get the clients IP address from the socket! Now store that IP adddresses.
- Now the group owner knows all IP address. So you can send messages to any device, just make a good routing

Comment: Thanks I did it, I will push the project on github soon.

Comment: @arezkibe Can you please give a link to your github project?

Comment: you sayed:"So you can send messages to any device, just make a good routing". how to make good routing? I face with "failed to connect to /192.168.49.24 (port 8988) after 5000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)"

Comment: As of this writing (API level 33/Android 13), organizing a Wifi Direct Group is only necessary for support of "legacy" devices. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager?authuser=1#createGroup(android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener)