# Connecting multiple devices and transferring data through Wifi Direct without access point

Tags: android, wifi-direct

hi I am developing an application using wifi Direct . I want to send data from mobile A to mobile B & from mobile B to mobile C & C to D etc using Wifi Direct.
I am able to send data from A to B and B to C & C to D,but with access point(group owner). I have done R&D on this and found some [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251610/wifi-direct-android-4-0-with-multiple-3-devices) that with out Access Point it is not possible.

Is there any way to approach this kind of data transfer or avoid this limitation or we have any alternative solution or paid SDK .Please help .

Comment: So why not use the Access Point feature to do a 1-to-many connection?

Comment: the challenge is to work without access point and Share A mobile to E Mobile. A can connect to B with limited distance.simillarly A can't reach C , so i need to send B to C which can be reachable.

Comment: Ok so you want to make *a chain of connections* rather than have a central point. Got it, but I don't know the answer to that. I'll upvote and good luck to you

Comment: trying for solution,thanks - shkschneider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently on android in wifi-direct, you can only create one-to-many connections (which includes one-to-one). In these connections one guy will become the group owner and other will connect to it. The guy who connected to the group owner cannot be part of another group (though its not explicitly mentioned anywhere, just like you I did my R&D when I was building an app using wifi-direct).

I do not think currently it is possible on android, so there won't be any SDKs available for this. This and connection troubles is one of the major reasons you won't find many apps on Play Store using wifi-direct.

But what you want is possible on Bluetooth (although bluetooth comes with its own sets of limitations of shorter range and less speed). Try reading on [Piconet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piconet)
 and [scatternet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatternet). In scatternets, you can create even Many-to-Many connections.

Comment: @Nithin Wifi-hotspot also creates an Access point in one of the devices and the other devices connect to the Access Point. Hence, same drawbacks... I wanted to implement the same thing six months ago that you are trying now... but unfortunately hit a dead end with wifi-based technologies

Comment: HI @unrealsoul007 so how does app like Xender achieve this functionality?

Comment: Xender only allows One To many connections and most of the use case for xender is one to one...? Xender on android uses wifi hotspot to connect devices. @vishnukhaunte What functionality of xender are you referring here?